# Black IPA Yeast Blend

Tags: yeast, ipa

My homebrew club hosted a Fantasy Homebrew Draft, where each brewer drafted an ingredient round by round. The rules are you have to brew with and only with 6 of 8 ingredients you drafted. Finings and Water agents are exempt.

I've come up with a Black IPA recipe that should be solid. However, my drafted yeast is Multi Strain Culture/Blend.

So, my question is what is a good blend of yeasts for a Black IPA that will finish from 1.075 to 1.013 to 1.011?

Thanks!

Comment: What do the rules say "Multi Strain Culture/Blend" means?  You can always pitch two yeasts that you'd normally pitch for an American IPA.